# Array of Dictionary Objects changes after sending to firebase cloud function in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have an array of dictionary objects called `assets`, when printed out in Swift, it shows:

```
[
    ["assetType": "video", "assetPath": "some_path"],
    ["assetType": "image", "assetPath": "some_other_path"]
]
```

which is perfect, however, after I send it to my firebase cloud function and print it out in the cloud function, `assets` becomes:

```
[
    {
        "assetType": ["video", "image"],
        "assetPath": ["some_path", "some_other_path"]
    }
]
```

Why does this happen? How should I solve this problem?

**------------------------------UPDATE------------------------------**

I use `Alamofire` module to perform http request:

```
Alamofire.request(
    "https://....",
    method: .post,
    parameters: [
        "assets": assets
    ]
)
```

**------------------------------UPDATE 2------------------------------**

My cloud function is as follows:

```
exports.testFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const { assets } = req.body;
    return res.status(200).send(assets)
})
```

which immediately sends back `assets` as soon as it's called

Comment: Someone voted to close this question because it's off topic because it's asking "why isn't this code working?", first of all, I'm not asking that, I personally think my code should be working. Second of all, If I can't ask it here, where do you think I should go to ask this question?

Comment: maybe this has something to do with the cloud function. not your swift code.

Comment: @S1LENTWARRIOR, Thank you for you reply, my firebase cloud function immediately sends back `assets`, without doing anything with it. But somehow this happens. I've updated this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated: The `Alamofire` way of doing this is at the bottom**

I tried something else and can only answer the second part of the question: **How do I solve this problem?**. Apparently, not using `Alamofire` solves the problem, but I'm sure there's nothing wrong with `Alamofire`, there might be something missing, I will dig around more, but for now, an alternative to `Alamofire` is `URLSession`:

```
let session = URLSession.shared
let url: URL = URL(string: "https://...")!
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

do {
    request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(
        withJSONObject: [
            "assets": assets
        ],
        options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions()
    )
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, _, _) in
        if let responseData = data {
            print(String(data: responseData, encoding: .utf8)!)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

And it prints:

```
[
    {
        "assetType": "video",
        "assetPath": "some_path"
    },
    {
        "assetType": "image",
        "assetPath": "some_other_path"
    }
]
```

**---------------------------The Alamofire way--------------------------**

Read the documentation [here](http://%7B%22query%22:%7B%7D,%22body%22:%7B%22hash%22:%22-L84e-aHwBedm1FHhcqv%22,%22uid%22:%2252YgRFw4jWhYL5ulK11slBv7e583%22,%22post%22:%7B%22latitude%22:41.8349976,%22message%22:%22%22,%22longitude%22:-87.6573802,%22formattedAddress%22:%22Bridgeport,%20Chicago,%20IL,%20USA%22,%22assets%22:[%7B%22assetType%22:%22image%22,%22assetPath%22:%22post_assets/F9431BD2-DCF0-43DA-8B39-25DC9F0819F3/0%22%7D,%7B%22assetType%22:%22image%22,%22assetPath%22:%22post_assets/F9431BD2-DCF0-43DA-8B39-25DC9F0819F3/1%22%7D]%7D%7D%7D), apparently, I should add `encoding` options too:

```
Alamofire.request(
    "https://...",
    method: .post,
    parameters: [
        "assets": assets
    ],
    encoding: JSONSerialization(options: [])
)
```

And this problem will be solved.

Comment: its great that you figured out the solution by yourself and posted it as well. Now i'd encourage you to accept your answer as well.

Comment: @S1LENTWARRIOR, Thank you. Yeah I'll accept it in 24 hrs when I'm allowed to.